# How to force use of DirectX 10 libraries and .dll files when compiling and running a VS2017CE project on a system with DirectX 11?

Tags: visual-studio, directx, directx-11, directx-10

I have some old code that was written before DirectX 11 was a thing, and now I would like to compile and run it on a new machine. However, this programm throws an error when launched with d3d11.dll (because system overrides older d3d10.dll), and full migration is not something I've got time for right now. I would like to know if it is possible to deliberately launch this project with an older DirectX library, possibly through the use of more arcane IDE options.

Comment: What operating system are you trying to use to run this Direct3D 10 application? Systems with the DirectX 11 runtime also support Direct3D 10, 10.1, and DirectX 9.0c.

Comment: Also note that on modern versions of Windows, ``d3d10.dll`` is actually implemented using the ``d3d11.dll``, so both are going to get loaded even if you only use Direct3D 10.